# Monero - Json RPC - Method not found

Tags: methods, blockchain, rpc, wallet, cryptocurrency

Hey there i am using the most recent command line tools from monero:

monerod:

```
Monero 'Lithium Luna' (v0.12.3.0-release)
Started using: ./monerod
Running on: 127.0.0.1:18081
```

monero-wallet-rpc:

```
Monero 'Lithium Luna' (v0.12.3.0-release)
Started using: ./monero-wallet-rpc --wallet-dir /path/to/wallets/ --rpc-bind-port 28081 --disable-rpc-login
Running on: 127.0.0.1:28081
```

I am currently testing rpc calls from:

https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html

Most of them work, but there are many rpc calls which seem not working...

For example:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:28081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"refresh"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": -32601,
    "message": "Method not found"
  },
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

Can anyone refer to this?

I am using the most recent versions and the documentation is also up to date.

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command with the params option in the json.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:28081/json_rpc \
-d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"refresh","params":{"start_height":100000}}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using an --rpc-bind-port equivalent to that of the *testnet* wallet RPC port. Try using another value like 40000 and curl to that instead.

The relevant ports are here under the namespace 'config':

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/cryptonote_config.h